# Как защититься от переполнения стека?

Tags: c, стек

Очень интересует информация о том, как защищаются отказоустойчивые системы от переполнения стека. Например, большие сервера платежных систем, на которых крутится очень непростая логика, часто в сотнях и тысячах потоков. В таких сложных системах гарантировать, что стек не переполнится, - крайне сложно.

Моя работа заключается в написании разнообразного ПО, часто достаточно нетривиального, для промышленности, на **С**. И, пожалуй, основная задача - это не придумывание алгоритмов, а контроль всевозможных логических ошибок, переполнений, утечек, фрагментации, уязвимостей и много чего еще.

В моей практике внезапного неожидаемого переполнения стека еще не было, но я бы и не хотел, чтобы это произошло.

Мой вопрос:

Есть ли в операционных системах возможность запустить процесс, размер стека которого будет нестатическим? То есть, если стек оказывается исчерпан, то может ли система вместо убийства процесса расширить его стек, если памяти хватает? Ведь это делается элементарным способом на уровне отображения виртуальных адресных страниц. Пользовательский процесс даже не узнает, что его стек был расширен. Если такое поведение ОС задать возможно, то как это делается в **Linux** и **Windows**?

Comment: Как минимум в линуксе точно есть "бесконечный" стек, доводилось юзать когда-то давно

Comment: На Windows описываемое поведение реализуется по умолчанию. Сначала для стека выделяется 4 кб, а потом он может расти по мере необходимости. Заметьте, что это не мера для предотвращения переполнения стека (потому что выделять память для борьбы с утечкой памяти - это как выделять водку на борьбу с алкоголизмом). Пара ссылок по теме: [Compile-time stack requirements analysis with GCC](https://www.adacore.com/uploads/techPapers/Stack_Analysis.pdf), [Gnatstack](https://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/toolsuite/gnatstack)

Comment: Про утечки-то понятно. Код, с которым я работаю, утечками не страдает и никогда не страдал. От чего он страдает, так это от агрессивного использования стека для всяких там промежуточных буферов, которые используются для уменьшения фрагментации памяти и повышения быстродействия. И когда дело доходит до самой глубокой функции, то стек уже порядочно разбухает.

Comment: *"Код, с которым я работаю, утечками не страдает и никогда не страдал."* - [сильное заявление](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Extraordinary_claims_require_extraordinary_evidence)...

Comment: @VTT ...проверять его я конечно же не буду)

Comment: Я большей частью работаю с кодом на C. Даже если в коде используется куча, даже если программа достаточно сложна, все точки запроса и освобождения ресурсов весьма легко отыскать и проанализировать. К тому же высоко устойчивых системах стараются по максимуму использовать стек и статическую аллокацию при запуске, потому что это быстро и безопасно. Например, несколько систем удаленного сбора данных без передышки работают уже почти год на весьма скромных ПЛК с 128 МБ памяти. Утечек нет. А логика там весьма сложная - опрос множества разнородных объектов по нескольким протоколам и передача по TCP

Comment: Утечки больше характерны для **C++**. Мне довелось поработать в двух международных компаниях, и я видел, как большие (очень большие) команды разработчиков не в состоянии залатать все утечки и дыры в ПО для ip-телефона или браузера. Причина, конечно же, не в **C++**. **C++** не виноват в том, что предоставляет такие прекрасные и сильные возможности, а все вокруг только лишь стреляют себе в ноги, ага-ага)

Comment: Полешче, уважаемый. А то вас сейчас так занесет, что начнете рассказывать, будто программы написанные на С еще и работают быстрее...

Comment: @VTT, программы, написанные на **C**, работают чаще всего быстрее :D Даже если на **C++** писать без использования виртуальных методов и исключений, код в большинстве случаев будет медленнее. Причиной тому - более высокая нагрузка на регистры. Хотя в некоторых случаях на **C++** код получается быстрее, чем на **C**, например, при использовании шаблонных контейнеров, которые оказываются чуть более эффективны на этапе выполнения за счет того, что не используются лишние уровни косвенности и определение размеров смещения на этапе выполнения.

Comment: `ulimit -s unlimited` - снимает ограничения на размер стека.

Answer (score 0):

Вы точно можете узнать размер своего стека заранее и предсказать его переполнение:

```
     $ ulimit -s 
//вернет размер вашего стека в Мб, такой стек будет для всех программ
```

Вы также можете увеличить размер вашего стека заранее, подробнее об этом можно прочесть тут https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/ulimit_mc.txt.html

Если вы измените размер вашего стека в момент исполнения программы, то скорее всего(я не уверен), он не изменится и останется прежним.

Поэтому, резюмируя, скажу, что вы можете предохраниться от переполнения, зная его размер заранее, а как его динамически расширить на данный момент мне неизвестно.